# How to navigate frame on image tapped in a user control Universal Windows App?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

i have an image on Tapping it i was navigating to another page

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Tapped="Image_Tapped_1"/>
```

> C#

```
 private void Image_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var gameData = (sender as Image).DataContext as DataClass;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(GamePage), gameData);
    }
```

Now I have created a User Control for adaptive UI and my code look like this now

```
 <Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateMin600">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="image.(FrameworkElement.Width)" Value="NaN"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateMin0">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Tapped="image_Tapped_1" Width="250" />

</Grid>
```

The problem now is that how will i navigate to the other page the tapped property is not working with in the UserControl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code-behind of your user control (let's call it ImageControl), you will have to manage an event handler like this:

```
public sealed partial class ImageControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler ImageTapped;

    public void image_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImageTapped != null)
        {
            ImageTapped(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

And from XAML where you declare your ImageControl :

```
<local:ImageControl ImageTapped="ImageControl_ImageTapped" />
```

And finally from C# code behind :

```
private void ImageControl_ImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(YourOtherPage));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `((Frame)Window.Current.Content).NavigateTo`
Or if needed set a public property to the rootframe on the App.Xaml.cs so you can always access it.